# java.lang.ClassCastException while using Arrays.sort(Object [])

Tags: java

Below is my code snippet

```
package arrays.sort;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArraySortExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object[] myObjects = {
                new Integer(12),
                new String("foo"),
                new Integer(5),
                new Boolean("true"),
        };

        Arrays.sort(myObjects);

        for(int i = 0 ; i < myObjects.length;i++){
            System.out.println(myObjects[i].toString());
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at java.lang.Integer.compareTo(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
    at arrays.sort.ArraySortExample.main(ArraySortExample.java:15)
```

what can be a reason ?

Comment: How do you think those values should be sorted?

Comment: And that my friend is why generics was invented in Java i.e. with generics such logical errors are caught and handled at compile time.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i am just experimenting with code, so that i can go wrong and learn.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. You wrote some code with some goal in mind. What was that goal and why did you think this code would achieve it? If you're just writing random code, I don't understand why exceptions are unexpected.

Answer (score 4):

First, [all `Object`s in that array must implement the `Comparable` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[])), which they *do*, but they themselves are not comparable with respect to each other.

From the docs:

> Furthermore, all elements in the array must be mutually comparable (that is, `e1.compareTo(e2)` must not throw a `ClassCastException` for any elements `e1` and `e2` in the array).

There is no natural ordering between an `Integer`, a `String` and a `Boolean` that will satisfy `Arrays.sort`, so the above expectation fails.

Consider what it is you're doing again - why do you need to use arrays?  It may be the case that a `List<? extends Comparable<?>>` may suit your needs better.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already said, you have objects in your array that cannot be compared using the `compareTo()` method in `Comparable`, however, you can still do a sort by using a [comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) as long as you have a well defined way of ordering `Integer` and `String`.

Here is an example that orders objects based first on their class name and if they are the same class by using a `compareTo()`

```
Arrays.sort(myObjects, new Comparator<Object>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2)
    {
        String o1Class = o1.getClass().getCanonicalName();
        String o2Class = o2.getClass().getCanonicalName();
        int ret = o1Class.compareTo(o2Class);

        if (ret == 0) // Classes are the same
        {
            // Not type safe but it's only an example
            ret = ((Comparable)o1).compareTo(o2);
        }
        return ret;
    }
});
```

It's ugly, but it works provided all the objects in your array implement `Comparable`.  In reality, I would never do this, I'd consider going with Makoto's answer.